# angular-route how to prevent download first time, but allow later

Tags: angularjs, ajax, seo, angularjs-routing

I want my website to be indexed by search engines, so i created html version of website. I have two types of pages - list and detail. Every list item has link to detail.

Also i created `json api with django-rest-framework` for angular app.

When i open my website in browser, i found that after half of second my ng-view has been updated, and two `xhr` queries was executed:

```
- my_template.html
- my_list.json
```

This means that information has been downloaded TWICE. How to avoid that? It is costs a lot

Comment: yes, it's not twice, first - info displayed as html page, second - info displayed via xhr. Why it happends if urls are the same? I thought it has smart detection what do and what not to do

Answer (score 0):

It does not means that it has been download twice.It means that when you go to your website it first Load a `html` file then a service that provide data in `json format`.Obviously when you go to website it loads up